# Drupal commerce custom discount

Tags: commerce

I'm using the Drupal Commerce module.

I want to make a discount rule where if there are 3 or more products of type X, you get a discount of 40% on all type X products. I don't know how I can do this without affecting type Y. Can this be done by pricing rules?

Comment: I could really use some help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to make "products of type X" "products with taxonomy term X" instead, you could probably get away with using [Commerce Taxonomy Conditions](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_taxonomy_conditions). With it, you can create a product discount that applies 1) if an order has a certain quantity of a taxonomy and 2) if the current product has a certain taxonomy term.

If that didn't suite you, you could model the correct discount/inline conditions from that code... ripping out the taxonomy bits and replacing them with Drupal Commerce product types.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! I used pricing rules to look for the right SKU and then checked how many of these SKU's there are in the basket[image]

Aantal=Amount

I also added a rule for <3 items.